# Minimize height, above a hole, needed for getting a rectangle out of the hole.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, optimization

I am looking for a solution to a particular task of manipulating a rectangle out of a hole. I will be happy for any suggestions. I wasn't able to find any simplifications (e.g.: transferring the problem to a problem of manipulating a rod), which would lead to an equivalent optimum.

Problem: **Minimize height, above a hole, needed for getting a rectangle out of the hole**.

Illustration picture:
[image: rectangle in a hole]

Having rectangle with known sides
$$
w, h
$$
and having a hole with known width and height:
$$
a, b
$$
Minimize height, above the hole, needed for pulling the rectangle out of the hole
$$
min(x)
$$

**EDIT**
Two answers (one of them was edited, I will consult it later) suggested placing bottom left/right corner of a rectangle to upper left/right point of the hole and rotating rectangle as much as possible to the right/left. I think this is correct for a **"short"** rectangle.

I suggest following for a **"long"** rectangle:

When I take "long" rectangle, I think the height needed (*x*) is what the picture below shows:

[image: Long rectangle]

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

A figure worth a thousand words.

[image]

NOTE

Attached a MATHEMATICA script which calculates the maximum height clearance needed to free the frame

```
parms1 = {w -> 1, a -> 1.2, h -> 1.5, b -> 1.9};
parms2 = {w -> 1, a -> 1.6, h -> 1.7, b -> 2.1};
frame = {{-w/2, -h/2}, {w/2, -h/2}, {w/2, h/2}, {-w/2, h/2}};
s = (a - w)/2;
r = (b - h)/2;
g = {gx, gy};
R = RotationMatrix[theta];
ftg = Table[R.frame[[k]] + g, {k, 1, 4}];
lw[lambda_] :=  lambda {-w/2 - s, -h/2 - r} + (1 - lambda) {-w/2 - s, h/2 + r}
rw[lambda_] :=  lambda ftg[[2]] + (1 - lambda) ftg[[3]]
restr1 = (ftg[[1]] - lw[lambda]).(ftg[[1]] - lw[lambda]);
restr2 = ({w/2 + s, h/2 + r} - rw[mu]).({w/2 + s, h/2 + r} - rw[mu]);
restr3 = 0 < lambda < 1;
restr4 = 0 < mu < 1;

obj = ftg[[4]].{0, 1} /. parms1;
restrs = Flatten[{restr1 == 0, restr2 == 0, restr3, restr4}] /. parms1;
sol = NMaximize[Join[{obj}, restrs], {theta, gx, gy, lambda, mu}]
ftg0 = Join[ftg, {ftg[[1]]}] /. parms1 /. sol[[2]];
grfr = ListLinePlot[ftg0];
lw0 = lw[u] /. parms1;
glw = ParametricPlot[lw0, {u, 0, 1}];
grw = ParametricPlot[{w/2 + s, -h/2 - r} u + (1 - u) {w/2 + s, h/2 + r} /. parms1, {u, 0, 1}]; 
Show[grfr, glw, grw, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1.8]
x = obj - b/2 /. parms1 /. sol[[2]]
```

Follows two plots relative to `parms1` and `parms2` respectively

[image]

[image]

With $p_1 = (-w/2,-h/2), p_2 = (w/2,-h/2), p_3 = (w/2,h/2), p_4 = (-w/2,h/2)$ we form a frame $F_0 = \{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\}$ This frame rotated by $R(\theta)$ and translated by $g = (g_x,g_y)$ is now $F(\theta,g_x,g_y) = R(\theta)\cdot F_0 + g$. The restrictions are $p_1(\theta,g)\in l_w(\lambda),\ 0\le \lambda\le 1$ and $p_0=(a/2,b/2)\in l_r(\mu),\ \ 0\le \mu\le 1$. Here $l_r(\lambda)$ is the left hole wall and $l_r(\mu)$ is the rectangle side with extremum points $p_2(\theta,g)$ and $p_3(\theta,g)$. The clearance is given by $x = p_4(\theta,g)\cdot(0,1)-b/2$

Comment: Thanks! I guess, the minimal needed height is when the left/right bottom corner of rectangle is touching left/right upper corner of the hole and rectangle is rotated as much as possible (so as the height above the hole is minimal).

Comment: Yes. It is correct.

Comment: In your diagram, the point of contact with the ceiling is above the right-hand edge of the hole, and it's not obvious what happens when this is not the case. In fact I suspect your solution is invalid: if the point of contact is further right, we can't necessarily get this far; and if it's further left, we can't necessarily go any further.

Comment: Really it's not obvious. I prepared a MATHEMATICA script which shows that the highest point attained and when it occurs, clearly depends on the frame dimensions. I attached this script as a way to show this.

Comment: I don't understand Mathematica scripts, so I can't judge whether your script confirms your proposed solution. The point is this: if the point of contact is to the left of the right-hand edge of the hole (for instance), then it is not clear (to me, at least) where the centre of rotation of the rectangle is as it rotates. If it was at the right-hand edge of the hole (which it probably isn't), then the rectangle would be unable to move any further. Can you say where this centre of rotation is?

Comment: The script is self explanatory. The two cases shown are typical.  The first is in accordance with my answer (at the top) and the second is in accordance with your suspicions. My point is that all depends on the relative dimensions. Regards.

Comment: "The script is self-explanatory": you're kidding, right?

Comment: I hope now with the attached notes to the bottom, the script is less nebulous.

Comment: I agree that the solution depends on frame dimensions. The notes helped, I am not sure how theta and position of p0 is computed. But I can see your point. I updated my question two days ago, I think  we agree on a position of a frame at which the height above the hole is maximal.

Comment: $p_0$ is the corner in which the rectangle right lateral glides.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Here is what the diagram should look like

[image]

Notice that the left most point of the rectangle is on the line that is with the floor?

Could you take it from there using similar triangles?

Note that there is a gap, because if $a=w$, then the height needed to pull it out would just be $h$, so $a>w$ in this case to solve the not-so-straightforward case.

Comment: thanks for a hint! I would say that solution is:
x = h*w/a

Comment: But If the rectangle is too long (h>>w), than i think it is more complicated.